# How to set org-mode header properties globally?

Tags: org-mode

I am trying to set the following org-mode tangle property ([mkdirp](https://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-Source-Code.html)), which

> creates parent directories for tangled files if the directory does not
> exist. A ‘yes’ value enables directory creation whereas ‘no’ inhibits
> it.

Apparently, it makes sense to set it for all relevant code blocks. My question is:

*Is there a way to set a header property/argument like this globally for the entire .org file?*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

File-level properties can be set like this:

`#+PROPERTY: header-args :mkdirp yes`

Language-specific arguments can be set with this syntax (setting property `p1` to value `v1`):

`#+PROPERTY: header-args:lang :p1 v1`

If you want to add properties without resetting everything else to default, use `lang+`, as in the following - it doesn't modify the previously set `p1` when setting `p2`. Without the `+`, `p2` would be set, but `p1` would revert to the default value

`#+PROPERTY: header-args:lang+ :p2 v2`.

File-level properties need to be evaluated (`C-c C-c` on the line, or close and re-open the buffer) to take effect.

Finally, rather than file-level, you can set properties at each `* Header` level with the `PROPERTIES` drawers:

```
* Header
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:lang: :property_1 v1 :property_2 v2
:header-args:lang+: :property_n value_n
:END:
```

These take effect immediately, and do not need to be evaluated.

See https://orgmode.org/manual/Property-Syntax.html for details